# ISPN000313 error in infinispan

Tags: java, wildfly, infinispan, jgroups, infinispan-8

I'm new to **Infinispan** and I'm using **Infinispan 8.1**.I just wanted to gain some knowledge on this **ISPN000313** error code.I have done a lot of research about this error code,but nothing helps me to understand it.

I also want to know when this error will happen,why it is happened and how to solve this error.

Answer (score 3):

The error message says `Lost data because of abrupt leavers [address list]`. Several nodes were suspected (crashed, were unresponsive or unreachable due to network partition) and the number of them is greater than `numOwners - 1`, therefore some entries might have been lost.

Please be specific what's unclear about that.